# GetFeatureInfo request from GeoServer responds with empty array

Tags: geoserver, leaflet, getfeatureinfo, vue.js

I am using the `vue-leaflet` and `axios` plugin in `vue.js` to make a GetFeatureInfo request to WMS tile layers served by Geoserver/Geowebcache for a certain point on the map, defined as `marker`.
I am getting empty responses for my request and I don't know where I am taking the wrong turn.

I have defined `l-map`, `l-tile-layers` (the background maps) and `l-wms-tile-layers`(the cached WMS tile layers served by GeoServer) as follows:

```
<l-map
      ref="map"
      v-model="zoom"
      v-model:zoom="zoom"
      :center="center"
      :options="{zoomControl:false, attributionControl:false}"
      :minZoom="minzoom"
      @click="addMarker"
    >

    <!-- Background maps: -->
    <l-tile-layer
      v-for="tileProvider in tileProviders"
      :key="tileProvider.name"
      :name="tileProvider.name"
      :visible="tileProvider.visible"
      :url="tileProvider.url"
      :attribution="tileProvider.attribution"
      layer-type="base"/>

    <!-- Layers from Geoserver as cached tile layers: -->
    <l-wms-tile-layer
      v-for="wmsLayer in getCheckedLayers"
      :key="wmsLayer.path"
      :layers="wmsLayer.path"
      :format="format_tile"
      :transparent="true"
      :tiled="true"
      :zIndex="wmsLayer.zindex"
      :base-url="wmsurl"
      :visible="true"
      :opacity="wmsLayer.opacity"
    >
    </l-wms-tile-layer> 
  
    </l-map>
```

`l-map` uses EPSG:3857 by default and so does `l-tile-layer`. The layers I uploaded to GeoServer are also EPSG:3857. Yet Geowebcache saves the cached layers in the local `gwc` directory as for example `EPSG_900913_11`, so I assume it uses EPSG:900913, which I read is a deprecated version of EPSG:3857. I also defined EPSG:3857 as a grid set in Geowebcache standards, so I wonder why it's not using it.

Now my problematic part: The GetFeatureInfo request:

```
data() {
            return {
                base_URL: 'http://localhost:8600/geoserver/wms?request=GetFeatureInfo&service=WMS&version=1.1.1',
                layers: '',
                srs: 'EPSG%3A3857',
                format: 'image%2Fpng', // alternatively: 'application/json'
                bbox: null,
                width: 256, // width of map output in pixels
                height: 256, // height of map output in pixels
                query_layers: '',
                info_format: 'application/json', // alternatively: 'application/json'
                x: 0, // X ordinate of query point on map, in pixels
                y: 0, // Y ordinate of query point on map, in pixels
                point_info: [],
            }
        },
        methods: {
            // get feature info in defined format (e.g. geojson)
            getFeatureInfo(marker, map) {
                // const map = this.$refs.map.leafletObject

                // First, build the URL depending on which layer has activeTooltips set to true
                
                this.layers = layerPath;
                this.query_layers = layerPath;
                this.bbox =  map.getBounds().toBBoxString();
                this.width = map.getSize().x;
                this.height = map.getSize().y;
                var point = map.latLngToContainerPoint(marker, map.getZoom());
                this.x = point.x;
                this.y = point.y;
           
                const feat_url = this.base_URL+
                    '&layers='+this.layers+
                    '&styles=&srs='+this.srs+
                    '&format='+this.format+
                    '&bbox='+this.bbox+
                    '&width='+this.width+
                    '&height='+this.height+
                    '&query_layers='+this.query_layers+
                    '&info_format='+this.info_format+
                    '&x='+this.x+
                    '&y='+this.y;
                

                // Next, make the get request
                axios.get(feat_url)
                .then((response) => {
                    this.point_info = response.data;
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    console.log(error);
                })
            }
        },
```

An example: I want to get the Feature Info for a selected WMS tile layer for the **coordinates** (latlong): (48.804813, 9.166788). The **bounding box** (bbox) was calculated by the function above as (8.953857421875002,48.66262313606079,9.412536621093752,48.8703607224138)and the **width and height** in pixels as (1336 918). The latlong **coordinates** where translated to pixels (620, 290).
When running the GetFeatureInfo request for that point I am getting an empty JSON response:

```
{
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [],
    "totalFeatures": "unknown",
    "numberReturned": 0,
    "timeStamp": "2022-03-23T14:19:44.220Z",
    "crs": null
}
```

When I change the `srs` in the GetFeatureInfo request from `EPSG:3857` to `EPSG:4326` I do get responses but they obviously don't match with the actual data point.

Any ideas what could the issue that cause empty responses despite the data being available?

Comment: You need to decide if you are using tiles (and so want a WMTS endpoint) or WMS where GeoServer will make some guesses and hope for the best that it can work out what you want. You will want to use EPSG:3857 through out though. Also the XY or IJ is in pixels not geographic coordinates.

Comment: Thanks @IanTurton. I am using tiles, see `<wms-tile-layer>` where I also set `tiled=true`. The XY I use for the GetFeatureInfo request are in pixels and I am using EPSG:3857 through out, as described in my post. As I understand using tiled maps would not make a difference for the GetFeatureInfo endpoint? The GetMap request that I am sending in `<wms-tile-layer>` itself works perfectly, it's just the GetFeatureInfo request that's not doing what I want. And the funny thing is that the GetFeatureInfo request works if I use EPSG:4326 but it's not working when I use EPSG:3857. Any suggestions?

Comment: UPDATE: I think the problem is that the `getBounds` function returns the bounding box coordinates in `latlng` and I need them in `meters`, which is the unit of EPSG:3857. Also, I calculate the bounds for the map object, and I think I rather need them for the tile layer. I have no idea how to get the **bounding box in meters for the tile layer** from within leaflet/leaflet. I can access them using the Geoserver GUI but I have a large number of tile layers and would like to access the bounding box coordinates from within vue/leaflet. Any ideas?

Comment: Hence, my suggestion that you use the WMTS end point, then you will know the bounds of the tiles.

Comment: @IanTurton Great, I will try that. Can you tell me the technical difference between the Geoserver+Geowebcache WMS endpoint with tiled=true (I am actually getting tiled layers from the Geoserver GetMap request) and the WMTS endpoint? And does a switch to the WMTS endpoint solve the issue that I need a bounding box in units of meters (since I am using EPSG:3875) instead of latlng?

Comment: in the first case, GeoServer chops up a random WMS request and hopes it matches a tile scheme. With a WMTS your client "knows" where each tile goes. All of this should be handled by the client with out you needing to do any maths or conversions. But I'm not a leaflet user so I don't know what's up

Comment: you can convert the latlng bounding box you get from map.getBounds() to EPSG:3857 using http://proj4js.org

Answer (score 1):

In the end I solved it, as @copossum suggested by converting the bounding box from latlng to my CRS's units, in my case meters (I am using EPSG:3857). I did not use proj4js but simply leaflet's `CRS.EPSG3857.project()` function.

Here's my solution:

```
data() {
            return {
                base_URL: 'http://localhost:8600/geoserver/wms?request=GetFeatureInfo&service=WMS&version=1.1.1',
                layers: '',
                srs: 'EPSG:3857',
                format: 'image/png', // alternatively: 'application/json'
                bbox: [],
                width: 256, // width of map output in pixels
                height: 256, // height of map output in pixels
                query_layers: '',
                info_format: 'application/json', // alternatively: 'application/json'
                x: 0, // X ordinate of query point on map, in pixels
                y: 0, // Y ordinate of query point on map, in pixels
                point_info: [],
            }
        },
        methods: {
            // get feature info in defined format (e.g. geojson)
            getFeatureInfo(marker, map) {
                // const map = this.$refs.map.leafletObject

                // First, build the URL depending on which layer has activeTooltips set to true
                var layer_selected = this.getCheckedLayers.filter(obj => {
                    return obj.activeTooltips === true
                    });
                var layerPath = layer_selected[0].path;
                
                this.layers = layerPath;
                this.query_layers = layerPath;
                var bounds = map.getBounds();
                var sw = bounds.getSouthWest();
                var ne = bounds.getNorthEast();
              
                // project the latlng bounds to meters (EPSG:3857)
                sw = CRS.EPSG3857.project(sw);
                ne = CRS.EPSG3857.project(ne);
                console.log('sw_pr: '+sw+'ne_pr: '+ne)
               
                this.width = map.getSize().x;
                this.height = map.getSize().y;
                var point = map.latLngToContainerPoint(marker, map.getZoom());
                this.x = point.x;
                this.y = point.y;
           
                const feat_url = this.base_URL+
                    '&layers='+this.layers+
                    '&styles=&srs='+this.srs+
                    '&format='+this.format+
                    '&bbox='+this.bbox+
                    '&width='+this.width+
                    '&height='+this.height+
                    '&query_layers='+this.query_layers+
                    '&info_format='+this.info_format+
                    '&x='+this.x+
                    '&y='+this.y;
    

                // Next, make the get request
                axios.get(feat_url)
                .then((response) => {
                    console.log(response.data)
                    this.point_info = response.data;
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    console.log(error);
                })
            }
        },
```